# Oracle select latest record if another column is null

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two columns for example. `A` is a `Varchar2` and `B` is a `date` column.

Data sample:

```
A            B
----------   -----------
10/27/15     
10/28/15     Y
```

How do I write a sql which will check `max(A)` record if `B` is `NULL`, and if it is then only select it. So in this scenario no rows should return.

I hope that made sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*
      from (select s.*
            from sample s
            order by a desc
           ) s
      where rownum = 1
     ) s
where s.B is null;
```

This is slightly simpler in Oracle 12+:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*
      from sample s
      order by a desc
      fetch first 1 row only
     ) s
where s.B is null;
```

An alternative uses conditional aggregation:

```
select max(a)
from sample
having max(a) = max(case when b is null then a end);
```

Comment: So which of your first and third method is the fastest?

Comment: If I have a another column, `C`, which is PK, can I use row_number window function on it and order it by `B` descending order?

Comment: If you have an index on `sample(a)` then the first two should be faster than the third.